# How to remove a stuck bayonet-mounted light bulb?

Tags: light-fixture

The bulb looks like this.

[image: Bayonet-mount]

It's been mildly broken from my earlier effort to remove the light. I've tried holding at the base, pushing it in a bit, twisting left/right and then trying to take it out, but this hasn't worked. I've had this fitting for many years but have never had a problem removing the bulb before using this procedure. I can still twist left/right but for some unknown reason the bulb will not come out when pulled.

The light fitting itself looks like this

[image: Fitting]

Comment: Classic answer: use a cut potato and push it into the socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would disassemble the fixture so you can get to the socket and bulb itself.  Normally you push in, turn left and pull, but it sounds like something is wrong.   Go with a quality LED and you'll never have to replace it again.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect the wires from the socket and discard the socket with the stuck globe.  Wire in a new Edison base socket and insert a proper globe.  After experiencing significant problems with bayonet sockets I totally avoid them as much as possible.

Comment: Why would you install a lamp socket instead of an integrated-emitter fixture to begin with?

Comment: Also, after 6 years, the OP has probably got this worked out...